# How can I use SIMD to accelerate XOR two blocks of memory?

Tags: c, xor, simd

I want to XOR two blocks of memory as quickly as possible, How can I use SIMD to accelerate it?

My original code is below:

```
void region_xor_w64(   unsigned char *r1,         /* Region 1 */
                       unsigned char *r2,         /* Region 2 */
                       int nbytes)       /* Number of bytes in region */
{
    uint64_t *l1;
    uint64_t *l2;
    uint64_t *ltop;
    unsigned char *ctop;

    ctop = r1 + nbytes;
    ltop = (uint64_t *) ctop;
    l1 = (uint64_t *) r1;
    l2 = (uint64_t *) r2;

    while (l1 < ltop) {
        *l2 = ((*l1)  ^ (*l2));
        l1++;
        l2++;
    }
}
```

I wrote one myself, but little speed increased.

```
void region_xor_sse(   unsigned char* dst,
                       unsigned char* src,
                       int block_size){
  const __m128i* wrd_ptr = (__m128i*)src;
  const __m128i* wrd_end = (__m128i*)(src+block_size);
  __m128i* dst_ptr = (__m128i*)dst;

  do{
    __m128i xmm1 = _mm_load_si128(wrd_ptr);
    __m128i xmm2 = _mm_load_si128(dst_ptr);

    xmm2 = _mm_xor_si128(xmm1, xmm2);
    _mm_store_si128(dst_ptr, xmm2);
    ++dst_ptr;
    ++wrd_ptr;
  }while(wrd_ptr < wrd_end);
}
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? The SIMD facilities available to you are very platform-specific.

Comment: @JasonR 64 bits linux supporting SSE4.2

Comment: You can try unrolling your loop. It's hard to get a large performance gain when you're not doing a lot of crunching per output value. Also, be careful as to the alignment of your buffers if you're going to use aligned load/store instructions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The more important question is why would you want to do it manually. Do you have an ancient compiler that you think you can outsmart? Those good old times when you had to manually write SIMD instructions are over. Today, in 99% of cases compiler will do the job for you, and chances are than it will do a lot better job. Also, don't forget that there are new architectures coming out every once in a while with more and more extended instruction set. So ask yourself a question — do you want to maintain N copies of your implementation for each platform? Do you want to constantly test your implementation to make sure it is worth maintaining? Most likely the answer would be no.

The only thing you need to do is to write the simplest possible code. Compiler will do the rest. For instance, here is how I would write your function:

```
void region_xor_w64(unsigned char *r1, unsigned char *r2, unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        r2[i] = r1[i] ^ r2[i];
}
```

A bit simpler, isn't it? And guess what, compiler is generating code that performs 128-bit XOR using [`MOVDQU`](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc184.htm) and [`PXOR`](http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc269.htm), the critical path looks like this:

```
4008a0:       f3 0f 6f 04 06          movdqu xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1]
4008a5:       41 83 c0 01             add    r8d,0x1
4008a9:       f3 0f 6f 0c 07          movdqu xmm1,XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*1]
4008ae:       66 0f ef c1             pxor   xmm0,xmm1
4008b2:       f3 0f 7f 04 06          movdqu XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1],xmm0
4008b7:       48 83 c0 10             add    rax,0x10
4008bb:       45 39 c1                cmp    r9d,r8d
4008be:       77 e0                   ja     4008a0 <region_xor_w64+0x40>
```

As @Mysticial has pointed out, the above code is using instruction that support unaligned access. Those are slower. If, however, a programmer can correctly assume an aligned access then it is possible to let compiler know about it. For example:

```
void region_xor_w64(unsigned char * restrict r1,
                    unsigned char * restrict r2,
                    unsigned int len)
{
    unsigned char * restrict p1 = __builtin_assume_aligned(r1, 16);
    unsigned char * restrict p2 = __builtin_assume_aligned(r2, 16);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        p2[i] = p1[i] ^ p2[i];
}
```

The compiler generates the following for the above C code (notice `movdqa`):

```
400880:       66 0f 6f 04 06          movdqa xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1]
400885:       41 83 c0 01             add    r8d,0x1
400889:       66 0f ef 04 07          pxor   xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*1]
40088e:       66 0f 7f 04 06          movdqa XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1],xmm0
400893:       48 83 c0 10             add    rax,0x10
400897:       45 39 c1                cmp    r9d,r8d
40089a:       77 e4                   ja     400880 <region_xor_w64+0x20>
```

Tomorrow, when I buy myself a laptop with a Haswell CPU, the compiler will generate me a code that use 256-bit instructions instead of 128-bit from the same code giving me twice the vector performance. It would do it even if I didn't know that Haswell is capable of it. You would have to not only know about that feature, but write another version of your code and spend some time testing it.

By the way, it seems like you also have a bug in your implementation where the code can skip up to 3 remaining bytes in the data vector.

At any rate, I would recommend you trust your compiler and learn how to verify what is generates (i.e. get familiar with `objdump`). The next choice would be to change the compiler. Only then start thinking about writing vector processing instructions manually. Or you gonna have a bad time!

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Forget my comment. I was a little too distracted to notice that you mention the alignment stuff at the end.

Comment: In the meantime, I'll note that increasing the data-type size isn't actually gonna help unless you go all the way up to `__m128i`. Since even 64-bit integer alignment isn't enough to remove the need for `movdqu`.

Comment: I've never actually used that since I do most of my work in MSVC. I've found that in most cases, if a simple loop happens to be critical to performance, there are usually higher-level transformations that can be done to get more improvement than just simple vectorization. But that said, these transformations are application-specific and not really that easy to do sometimes. So hacking away with compiler extensions is probably the easier way for most people.

Comment: @Mysticial: Cannot agree with you more! The best is to use a profiler :) Anyways, I have extended the answer with an example of how to hint a compiler about alignment to get it to produce `movdqa`. I think it is still better than writing SIMD manually. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I use GCC compiler and it seems not so smart as you said. even with '-O3' option, the code don't performs 128-bit XOR.

Comment: By the way, I think the SIMD XOR code is OK, since 'dst_ptr' and 'wrd_ptr' are pointers to a 128bits uint.

Comment: @foool: I have used GCC to compile, so the result you see is from GCC (version 4.7.2 that comes with Fedora 18). However, optimization flags is half of the job. Check for what architecture you are compiling. By default, GCC will stick with "generic" x86_64 because it cannot assume   more on its own. So specify `-march` (or both `-march` for lower and `-mtune` for desirable). For example, you can say `-march=native` to ask GCC to generate code for the current architecture.

Comment: @foool: Yes, XOR code itself is OK. But given that input is coming from `unsigned char *`, how would it process 3 bytes (given that it is even less than a single `int`)?

Comment: @VladLazarenko： Thanks a lot, this fuction is part of my code, an alignment check fuction will make sure the size is a multiple of 128 bits.

Comment: Gosh, almost always I have found that hand-optimizing code beats the compiler in performance critical sections. This is because you as the programmer have specific domain knowledge that the compiler does not!

Comment: 99% of the time is an overstatement.  There are many SO questions about vectorizing something that gcc doesn't auto-vectorize at all.  Sometimes clang or ICC will.  Or sometimes gcc will but clang won't.  You can do a lot with SSE4 / AVX2 beyond just trivial pure vertical stuff like this.  I mean yes enabling auto-vectorization by using `restrict` where appropriate is good, and compilers will do a good job for cases like this.  In more complicated cases involving widening or narrowing, they sometimes do a *terrible* job  auto-vectorizing where you can beat them by a factor of 2 or more.

Answer (score 0):

As the size of the region is passed by value why wouldn't the code be:

```
void region_xor_w64(unsigned char *r1, unsigned char *r2, unsigned int i)
{
    while (i--)
        r2[i] = r1[i] ^ r2[i];
}
```

or even:

```
void region_xor_w64(unsigned char *r1, unsigned char *r2, unsigned int i)
{
    while (i--)
        r2[i] ^= r1[i];
}
```

If there's a preference towards going forwards ('up memory') and for using pointers, then:

```
void region_xor_w64(unsigned char *r1, unsigned char *r2, unsigned int i)
{
    while (i--)
        *r2++ ^= *r1++;
}
```

Comment: HW prefetch typically works slightly better going forwards.  The L2 streamer in Intel CPUs works equally well in either direction, but I'm not sure about L1d prefetch.  And if you have AVX, then you usually want the compiler to use pointer-increments not indexed addressing modes so writing it the OP's way is closer to the asm you want.  Except that doesn't matter for what compilers actually do.

Comment: (Or for Sandybridge/IvyBridge, also with SSE2 for the store and `pxor xmm0, [rsi]` if the compiler aligns an input so it can fold a load in the main loop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've added a version for going 'up' memory and using pointers, but still not using a for(...) loop which saves a comparison per cycle.  Even better on CPU that track zero in the flags associated with the register - think Z80 DJNZ ;-)

Comment: You're writing in C, not asm.  A decent compiler will already do that transformation for you, or depending on the target ISA optimize away the counter entirely and do a pointer comparison.  To get it to auto-vectorize with the least overhead, your best bet is probably to use `unsigned char *restrict r1` to promise the compiler the blocks don't overlap, so it can leave out an overlap check.  https://godbolt.org/z/KYrCw_ shows how it compiles with gcc/clang/MSVC for x86-64.  MSVC fails to auto-vec. You can check out AArch64, PowerPC (which has a dec-and-branch insn, IDK if it'll be used), etc.

Comment: TL:DR: these compile to basically identical asm vs. the other answer.  But the decreasing version tricks GCC into shuffling its SIMD vector to reverse the order before XOR, because GCC is not super smart.  Oh, and MSVC *does* vectorize the version in the other answer with a `for` loop, but not the `while(i--)` version here, because MSVC is dumb.  So your changes result in a ~16x slowdown on one of the widely-used x86 compilers.