# How to Improve XORing of large uint64 arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11, xor, avx2

I want to xor large shifted arrays, following is portable version of that function for easy of explanation. How I can improve this computation? I have tried using AVX2 but didnt see much improvement. Currently for the DB showing in the example below it takes 50ms to process everything, which is 12 GB/s, I will appreciate any tips to improve the computation.

```
#include <iostream>

uint64_t partition_size = 4096;
uint64_t entry_size = 32; // bytes
uint64_t DB_size = 16777216;
uint64_t *DB = new uint64_t[DB_size * entry_size/64];


//partition_index will be a random multiple of partition_size, e.g. 0, 8192, 4096 etc
//random_offset will be a random number in [0, partition_size]
void xor_shifted_arrays(uint32_t partition_index, uint32_t random_offset, uint64_t *result)
{
    auto uint64_per_entry = entry_size / sizeof(uint64_t);

    int shift_offset;
    uint32_t shift;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < partition_size  ; i = i + 1)
    {
        shift = (i + random_offset) & (partition_size - 1);
        shift_offset = shift * uint64_per_entry;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < uint64_per_entry; j=j+1){
            result[shift_offset + j] = result[shift_offset + j] ^ DB[partition_index + j];  
        }
        partition_index = partition_index + uint64_per_entry;
    }
}
```

Update:
Here is godbolt :https://godbolt.org/z/j14av3fGq
Also ran this code on two instances.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz running MacOS 13.6, 16 GB DDR4 RAM, compiler Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)

AWS r7i.2xlarge Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8488C with Ubuntu, 64 GB DDR5 RAM, compiler g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0

Surprisingly it is 2x slower on Xeon !!

I am using compiler flag O3

Update2: I feel this may be useful, the above code gets called from outer functions something like this (not running code)

```
void outer_function(){
  uint64_t *result1 = new uint64_t[partition_size];
  uint64_t *result2 = new uint64_t[partition_size];
  uint64_t number_partitions = 4096;
  for (int i=0; i< number_partitions; i++){
      xor_shifted_arrays(i*partition_size,           some_rnd_gen(), result1)
  }
  for (int i=0; i< number_partitions; i++){
     xor_shifted_arrays(i*partition_size,                some_rnd_gen(), result2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note, in current C++ you hardly should have to use raw new/delete/pointers (they only increase the likelyhood for memory leaks) So instead of `uint64_t *DB = new uint64_t[DB_size * entry_size/64];` use `std::vector<std::uint64_t> DB(DB_size * entry_size/sizeof(std::uint64_t);` Also move your variables to main and at that main function to your example to make it a fully minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Any question concerning the speed or performance of C++ code must be accompanied by the compiler options used to build the program.  The most important of these options are the *optimization settings*.  If you are running an unoptimized or "debug" build, the timings you are reporting are meaningless.

Comment: Hopefully your compiler (version/options?) is already auto-vectorizing that trivial inner loop with AVX2.  On what hardware? Is that close to theoretical max DRAM bandwidth?  If so, the only way to go faster is by cache-blocking the work so you get some cache hits.  (Or so the output is still in cache when later code reads it.)  Or other algorithmic changes to improve locality.

Comment: Also compile your code on https://godbolt.org/, you might find out your compiler is already doing a lot of smart things with vecorization in optimized builds. That's probably also why you don't see a lot of  improvement with manually written avx512 code.

Comment: With this much data and data independence you probably can benefit from parallelization/multithreading and making a small "pipeline" of your own where you process data in chuncks that fit in the cache of each core. In the end to find your real bottleneck use a profiler and measure what actually is going on.

Comment: Wait a minute, the inner loop is doing `j=j+4`, but the body isn't unrolled to use `j+1`, `j+2` etc.  So you're only touching 2 `uint64_t` elements per 64-byte cache-line of eight of them.

Comment: I have updated the answer, added more information about compile. I want to test single thread performance. Also @PeterCordes corrected the code

Comment: You should certainly try `result[shift_offset + j] ^= DB[partition_index + j]` in addition to everything else mentioned here. Also `j++` rather than `j=j+1`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
added

Comment: Xeon 8488C is vastly different in terms of memory bandwidth scaling with number of threads vs. your i7-7700K Kaby Lake.  The KBL system can more or less saturate DRAM with a single core, but the Sapphire Rapids Xeon needs most of its cores active to keep its DRAM controllers maxed out, with per-core bandwidth being lower than an older desktop chip ([Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260020)). See  https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/03/12/a-peek-at-sapphire-rapids/ for some SPR graphs.

Comment: @user207421: Those would be easier to read, especially the `^=` change, but compilers know they're exactly identical (at least when optimization is enabled, which is the only case that matters.  And the OP wouldn't be getting 12GB/s with optimization disabled for this loop.)

Comment: Does it mean this code is saturating the memory and for single thread there is nothing much to do ? I am still surprised by Xeon still, because I also tried doing av512 on Xeon and code for 4x slower @PeterCordes

Comment: AVX-512 was 4x slower?  You must have been doing something wrong; it should be the same speed as the compiler's auto-vectorized code.  If you literally just used `-O3` without `-march=native` or anything, then it would just be SSE2, but it's number of cache-lines in flight that matters, whether it's 4, 2, or 1 load/store buffer entries per cache line.  Especially with a sequential access pattern that lets the L2 streamer prefetcher work well.  If you did use `-O3 -march=native` or just `-mavx2` without a tuning option, then you'd be getting 256-bit loads/stores.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry by bad I indeed also turned on -march=native, but yes avx512 was slower so I reverted the code

Comment: And yes, DRAM or even L3 bandwidth is slow (especially on your Xeon) compare do how cheap a 256-bit SIMD xor is.  From L1d cache, SPR can do 3x 64-byte loads per clock to feed up to 2x 512-bit XORs per clock. https://uops.info/ (And  2x 64-byte stores per clock, although can't sustain that store throughput for commit to L1d cache.  So could probably do 64 bytes per clock if memory wasn't a bottleneck.  Or with just AVX2 or 256-bit AVX-512 vectors, more than 32 bytes per cycle.)  Even scalar integer would still bottleneck on per-core DRAM bandwidth at much less than 3 loads + 2 stores / clock.

Comment: 512-bit vectors would help if your data was hot in L1d cache, if you used them properly.  If not, probably not worth it.  So IDK what you did wrong with AVX-512, but probably not worth worrying about for this problem, unless you can cache-block things somehow.

Comment: Near duplicate of [How can I use SIMD to accelerate XOR two blocks of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15067119) - compilers already auto-vectorize (at least at `-O3` for GCC).  These days we're not limited to SSE2 like that 2013 question, and memory-alignment is often less important for good SIMD performance (or if memory is aligned, promising that to the compiler is sometimes totally irrelevant these days with AVX).  But the point stands that compilers already do a good job, you don't need intrinsics for this.

Comment: @PeterCordes so whats the verdict? if algorithm cant be changed then this is best possible? I was thinking to try implementing in rust to see if compiler do any better job, sorry if my questions are trivial , this is first time I am dealing with memory bound issue, mostly I have compute bound workloads

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect there's no room for improvement via manual micro-optimization.  Maybe a few percent if hardware prefetch helps on any CPUs, or from making your arrays aligned by 64.  `rustc` uses the same LLVM back-end as `clang` so I wouldn't expect a benefit there.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I forgot to mention on 32MB DB I am getting 16 GB/s on i7 and 20 GB/s on Xeon

Comment: Good to see that a DB smaller than your Xeon's L3 cache makes it a bit faster than DRAM on the Kaby Lake!  But only a bit because per-core memory bandwidth is so low, I'd assume.

Comment: Yeah I just wished Xeon is also reported same result at least because that would make life easier, so may be I should try switching to CLang?

Comment: Same result as your KBL desktop?  I have no idea why you'd expect it to be the same.  Naively you'd expect it to be way faster (more DRAM controllers at higher memory clocks). Actually you'd expect it to be way slower unless you get L3 cache hits, due to the higher uncore latency that ends up being a limiting factor for per-core memory bandwidth, like in the SKL-client vs. Broadwell-many-core Q&A I linked earlier.  But yeah, using the same compiler on both is a good idea, and clang is often pretty good.  Usually worth trying both on the same machine for code you care about.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes for sure I meant to say I would want Xeon to be better but since its more slower then I expect it be at least matching KBL

Comment: Not going to happen with a single-threaded memory-bound workload, unfortunately, unless it fits in L3 on the Xeon but not the desktop.  Like I said (in my answer on the Q&A I linked), the CPU-architecture reason is the higher un-core latency meaning the same number of in-flight requests / transfers has lower bandwidth.  (Or SPR might have more LFBs and superqueue entries than KBL, but not by enough to make up the difference.)  They're designed for workloads where all cores are using some memory bandwidth, so they don't over-design that part of each core.

Comment: Use an AMD (Threadripper or EPYC) if you want good single-core memory bandwidth on a many-core CPU.  https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/03/12/a-peek-at-sapphire-rapids/ includes a Zen3-based EPYC in the graph of single-core memory-bandwidth vs. working-set size - it comes in at about twice the SPR, about the same as the i9-12900K desktop chip.

Comment: Okay I can try AMD , I also tested what you said and L3 Cache on Xeon is 105  indeed when I try database of size 64 MB, it gives me 18 GB/s and then I try 128 MB it drops drastically to 12 GB/s . However compiler doesnt give any benefit, I tried Clang13 and same result. I am thinking may be then it is better to divide DB in 64MB blocks and process each one by one, that way it will be faster than processing whole . For example if DB is 128 MB then divide into two separate arrays and process first one and then the second one?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use a big number library. This is an example from **boost**: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/egs/bitops.html

Comment: @Red.Wave to be sure are you suggesting to use big integer library ?

Comment: @CryptoKitty what you're doing suggests that it's a big number. So, best effort would be search for the proper big number type. **boost** happens to provide 3 big integer types. And there's more if you search. I think there must be an MIT C++ big number out there too.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have added the sketch of outer function in case something can be done there

Comment: @CryptoKitty: Yes, cache-blocking to get L3 hits is worth doing, maybe L2.  `DB` can still be one contiguous array, you just loop over the first 0.5 MiB of each chunk of result / DB, then the second, then the third, etc. with an outer loop around your current code.  Per-core private L2 is much faster than L3 on big Xeons, and each core has 1 to 2 MiB of L2.  (2 MiB on SPR.)

Comment: @PeterCordes that makes sense, so I tired doing 64 MB and but didnt see the improvement so will do even more smaller chunks. How I did it is by changing outer loop to first loop on 1/8 of database for both results,  so for 512 MB data its 64 MB

Comment: @PeterCordes little surprising that no change in performance no matter how I chunk

Comment: I haven't really understood the access pattern; it's less simple than I thought.  I think DB[] reads overlap between subsequent iterations, so there's excellent locality there if it's still hot in L2 cache with small enough chunk size.  Especially if `uint64_per_entry` is supposed to be 4 uint64_t per 256 bits, not 32 uint64_t per 256 bytes like your code actually uses.  (Is this another case of your [mcve] not being what you're actually benchmarking?  That wouldn't happen if you had a correctness test and a benchmark for the code you're actually posting.)

Comment: Oh, either way, the inner loop `j` range is tiny.  I hadn't realized that based on the simple title about XORing large arrays.  I was thinking that inner-most loop size was what we were talking about as the chunk size.

Comment: @PeterCordes number_partitions  and partition_size are the longest loop, inner most is only 4, number_partitions loop jumps of chunks of data

Comment: Fix your code so it matches what you're saying it does.  In the code as posted, the inner loop goes from j=0 to j=31, since `256 / 8` is 32, as chtz pointed out.  `sizeof` works in bytes, not bits.  Use `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits` if you don't want to hard-code `64` for `uint64_t`.  Or C-style `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT`.  And write a unit test, although that would require a known-good implementation which you maybe don't have.

Comment: opps @PeterCordes sorry the entry size is in bytes I accidentally left it as bits here, so its entry_size=32 bytes, I wrote this simpler example from the larger code I wrote , and everything is in bytes there, I accidentally left entry_size as bytes

Comment: The details matter a lot when micro-optimizing.  Any other bugs that make this different from your real problem?  I'd recommend checking with a unit-test, like running both versions with the same random data and PRNG seed, and checking the results, because I don't really trust this code to actually do the same thing as your real code, after two (different but related) bugs already.  There might be others that don't look obviously wrong.  I don't know the high-level purpose of this XORing (error-correction codes? crypto?), so I don't know what it should be doing.

Answer (score 3):

These are mostly generic tips, which will help your compiler to optimize code (many of them were already in the comments):

- For array indexes/sizes always use `size_t` (or `ptrdiff_t` if you want to allow negative indexes). This will save the compiler from dealing with potential wrap-around or overflow behavior.
- Declare variables at the point you initialize them/in the scope you use them
- Declare all variables which never change after initialization as `const`. If the compiler knows their value, it can optimize multiplications or division with them, especially if they are powers of 2.
- Pass the pointer of arrays you modify as function parameter with a `__restrict` keyword (only do this, if you are sure that this array does not alias/overlap with other arrays). This often helps the compiler with unrolling and SIMD optimization.
- Compile your code with `-march=native` (or `-march=target_architecture`) to optimize for your local or some specific CPU architecture (additionally to `-O3`, of course).
- Just for readability: Instead of `A = A + B`, write `A += B`, (same with `^`/`^=`, etc). This usually does not matter for the compiler.

Assuming the `j=j+4` in your godbolt-link was a typo, and you meant `j+=1` (or `++j`) this results in very clean AVX2 code:

```
// assuming these are known at compile-time:
const size_t partition_size = 4096; 
const size_t entry_size = 256; // bits
const size_t DB_size = 16777216;

uint64_t *DB = new uint64_t[DB_size * entry_size/64];
const size_t uint64_per_entry = entry_size / sizeof(uint64_t);
//uint64_t *result = new uint64_t[partition_size]; // pass this as parameter

//partition_index will be a random multiple of partition_size, e.g. 0, 8192, 4096 etc
//random_offset will be a random number in [0, partition_size]
void xor_shifted_arrays(size_t partition_index, size_t random_offset, uint64_t *__restrict result)
{

    for (size_t i = 0; i < partition_size  ; i++)
    {
        const size_t shift = (i + random_offset) & (partition_size - 1);
        const size_t shift_offset = shift * uint64_per_entry;
        
        for (size_t j = 0; j < uint64_per_entry; j++){
            result[shift_offset + j] ^= DB[partition_index + j];    
        }
        partition_index += uint64_per_entry;
    }
}
```

Godbolt-Link: https://godbolt.org/z/Khs5aTPaK

I don't see much further possible improvements for this code. You need to read and write every `result` entry once together with the corresponding `DB` entry.
If you have control over memory management, you could make sure that pointers are aligned to page sizes (or at least to your SIMD-width)

Also if (for a different problem) some entries would be read or modified multiple times, you can try to re-arrange your loops, so that variables are less often read or written from/to memory.

Comment: added outer function sketch, in case something can be done there

Comment: @CryptoKitty with the extended problem you could reduce the number of accesses to your result vector by a lot. Btw: are you sure about `uint64_per_entry = entry_size / sizeof(uint64_t);`? Note that `sizeof` gives you the number of bytes not bits.

Comment: how can I reduce the number of access?

Comment: I accidentally left entry_size as bits, its in bytes and yes uint64_per_entry = entry_size / sizeof(uint64_t); is correct should be 4

Comment: Assuming `some_rnd_gen()` does not have weird side-effects, you can unroll 2 or 4 of your outer loop, and instead of shifting the `result`, shift all accesses to `DB` by `-random_offset`. You can then xor multiple DB-entries before xoring them to the `result` entry. (If you want a working implementation, provide a working [mre])

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL can vectorize simple codes easily and distributes the work to all cores. For example, following code computes XOR of 16 million 64-bit integers in 3 milliseconds with Ryzen 7900 (12 cores), making ~44GB/s bandwidth on dual-channel 4800MHz DDR5 memory (this is just a simple XOR of all elements, not exactly your algorithm, so it's not using caches efficiently but simply streaming data):

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 4096 * 4096;
    constexpr int numWorkers = 4096*32;
    GPGPU::Computer computer(GPGPU::Computer::DEVICE_CPUS);
    std::string nStr = std::string("constant int N = ") + std::to_string(N) + R"(;
    )";
    std::string nwStr = std::string("constant int stride = ") + std::to_string(numWorkers) + R"(;
    )";
    computer.compile(nStr+nwStr+R"(
    
        kernel void Xor(global unsigned long * dataIn, global unsigned long * dataOut)
        { 
            int id = get_global_id(0);
            unsigned long xorData = dataIn[id];
            for(int i=1;i<N/stride;i++)
            {
                xorData = xorData ^ dataIn[id + i*stride];
            }

            // reduced result
            dataOut[id]=xorData;
        })", "Xor");

    GPGPU::HostParameter dataIn = computer.createArrayInput<uint64_t>("dataIn",N);
    GPGPU::HostParameter dataOut = computer.createArrayOutput<uint64_t>("dataOut", numWorkers);
    auto parameters = dataIn.next(dataOut);

    uint64_t result = 0;
    size_t t;
    for (int rep = 0; rep < 20; rep++)
    {
        for (int init = 0; init < N; init++)
            dataIn.access<uint64_t>(init) = init;
        {
            GPGPU::Bench bench(&t);
            computer.compute(parameters, "Xor", 0, numWorkers, 256);

            // final pass on host-side with just numWorkers elements
            uint64_txorData = dataOut.access<uint64_t>(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < numWorkers; i++)
            {
                xorData ^= dataOut.access<uint64_t>(i);
            }
            result = xorData;
        }
        std::cout << "computation took " << t / 1000000000.0 << "s" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "xor: " << result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
computation took 0.0079244s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030533s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030468s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0031714s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030102s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030884s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029352s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029854s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029936s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029326s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030838s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0031311s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030022s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0031073s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029577s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0030004s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0031038s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029255s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.002938s
xor: 0
------------
computation took 0.0029927s
xor: 0
------------
```

I had to install Intel's Runtime to be able to use the CPU. Also tried GPU but pcie v4.0 has some bottleneck (being only around 32GB/s and outside of the CPU cache).

To control caching on L2 & L3 or to select cores explicitly, you can use device-fission feature of OpenCL. If you don't need OpenCL, you can still observe assembly output of program binary to see how it vectorizes the codes and take it for your own C++ hand-tuned AVX library.

Comment: OpenMP `#pragma omp parallel` might be easier to use and get basically the same results.  The challenge is parallelizing in coarse enough chunks to minimize overhead, so probably not for the inner loop.  Especially if cache-blocking the inner loop for L2 size, you'd want to make sure the same physical core re-reads the same chunk of `DB` or `result` every time.

Comment: OpenCL has device-fission feature to let physical cores be used independently and explicitly as devices. They can even be chosen with cache-topology queries. But computationally may not be as good as hand-tuned AVX codes, but still able to use caches good enough. Maybe a mapping from chunk id - to - core id could solve this cache problem. Ofcourse OpenMP is much easier to enable. But once done in OpenCL, GPUs and even FPGAs become an automatic transition, just in case.